# FFMPEG is not working centos linux server

Tags: php, linux, video, ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG for video thumbnails creation,

I have downloaded FFMPEG (ffmpeg-2.4.2.tar.bz2) and installed in server.

located in

> /usr/bin/ffmpeg

and used in this below code:

```
if($extension === 'mp4' OR $extension == 'MP4' )
{
$video = $timestamp.$imagename;
$videoname=substr($imagename,0, -4).$timestamp;
$image = "sites/default/files/content_images/{$videoname}-thumb.jpg";

var_dump($video);

$cmd="/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/sites/default/files/content_videos/".$video." -ss 00:00:14.435 -f image2 -vframes 1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/sites/default/files/content_images/$videoname-thumb.jpg";

$cmdstr = $cmd;
$locale = 'en_IN.UTF-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
echo exec($cmd);
```

but this command not working as i expect..

```
$cmd="/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/sites/default/files/content_videos/".$video." -ss 00:00:14.435 -f image2 -vframes 1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/sites/default/files/content_images/$videoname-thumb.jpg";
```

issue was video thumbnail is not created,when we upload videos.

any help great appreciation

Comment: Launch the command directly in the terminal using a test file and update your post with its output.

Comment: i have launched command in by using putty,i have given manually like            /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/sites/default/files/content_videos/0_14023100_1398692355Rock_star_video.mp4 -ss 00:00:14.435 -f image2 -vframes 1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/sites/default/files/content_images/0_14023100_1398692355Rock_star_video-thumb.jpg

Comment: this time created tumbnail,when i am uploading video dynamically it not creating

Answer (score 0):

Variable concatenation is wrong at the end of your cmd definition.
Try with :

```
[...]les/content_images/".$videoname."-thumb.jpg";
```

**Addendum :**
What are the rights on the output directory ?
Your CMD will be run with your webserver user (www-data on Debian systems, httpd on RH, etc...). Make sure directory ownership and/or write rights are set properly